# FreeOpcUa how to access method (from terminal)

Tags: python, raspberry-pi2, opc, opc-ua

https://github.com/FreeOpcUa
https://www.dexterindustries.com/grovepi/

Setup:

I'm using freeOpcUa on a Raspberry Pi combined with a GrovePi with sensors and actuators.

An OPC UA Server runs on the Raspberry Pi. Nodes and methods predefined in the server file work as they should and I can access them. I also can observe the nodes with the OPC-UA-client provided by FreeOpcUa.

My Problem:

FreeOpcUA provides an Ua-Modeler with which node models can be designed and exported to XML. the XML file can be imported by the server through code or terminal commands. And the new nodes can be observed as well with the opcua-client.

In the terminal where I imported the XML, I now want to execute a previously written method in the server script: `print_something_on_terminal("Hello World")` 
which I have defined as a method of the new node in the XML file which I have imported.

In the terminal on the running server. I can find the new node and the method as an object. But I haven't found a way yet to execute the method.
Has anyone faced this situation?

thx for any hint.

Answer (score 0):

Found out:

The Server class holds a method "def link_method(self, node, callback):"
so after you have imported the XML you need to link the node to the method...

After that it's executable